# Pulling Data onto a new sheet using multiple criteria. Only printing zeroes

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I am currently working on a project. THe project consists of two sheets, an Inventory sheet that houses all of the raw data, and the ad sheet where the data will be pulled and organized. I have written this code to pull data based off of two criteria. Variable d is the same headers as column E in the inventory sheet, and Column A in the ad sheet corresponds to M1:S1 on the inventory sheet.

Currently my code is only printing zeroes instead of the numbers in the specified range on the Inventory sheet.

Below is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, c As Range, d As Range
Dim f As String


Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

lastRow = Application.Max(ws.Range("E100000").End(xlUp).Row, _
                       ws.Range("M100000").End(xlUp).Row, _
                       ws.Range("S100000").End(xlUp).Row)

Set c = ActiveCell
Set d = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)

Do
    f = "=IFERROR(INDEX(<addrMS>, MATCH(1,INDEX(($A<rw>=<addrA>)*(d=<addrE>),0,1),0)),0)"
    f = Replace(f, "<rw>", c.Row)
    f = Replace(f, "<addrMS>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$2:$S$" & lastRow)
    f = Replace(f, "<addrA>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$1:$S$1")
    f = Replace(f, "<addrE>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow)

    c.Formula = f 'prints value in active cell
    Set c = c.Offset(0, 1) 
    Set d = d.Offset(0, 1) 
Loop While Not IsEmpty(d)
```

Comment: Why aren't you replacing the d value in the formula like you are replacing other values?

Comment: The d value is just keeping track of the cell above the active cell (which holds the header names that are matched in column e of the inventory sheet)

Comment: Are you sure that d should be in the formula?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it any other way. I am matching the headers (which are always gonna be one row above the active cell) with column e and matching column a of active cell with M1-S1 to find the corresponding data in M2-SlastRow

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code the first formula it produces looks like this.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Inventory'!$M$2:$S$123, MATCH(1,INDEX(($A3='Inventory'!$M$1:$S$1)*(d='Inventory'!$E$2:$E$123),0,1),0)),0)
```

Now unless you have a named range called **d** the first part of the formula will produce an error, and since you have an IFERROR the whole formula will evaluate to 0.

Perhaps d is meant to be the address of the range variable d?

This code will replace  in the formula string with the address of the range d refers to.

```
f = "=IFERROR(INDEX(<addrMS>, MATCH(1,INDEX(($A<rw>=<addrA>)*(<d>=<addrE>),0,1),0)),0)"
f = Replace(f, "<rw>", c.Row)
f = Replace(f, "<addrMS>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$2:$S$" & lastRow)
f = Replace(f, "<addrA>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$1:$S$1")
f = Replace(f, "<d>", d.Address)
f = Replace(f, "<addrE>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow)
```

Comment: This worked with turning the d variable into the correct address but I am still getting all 0s. Thank you for the help so far though

Comment: Once you've run the code have you tried stepping through one of the formulas using Formulas>Formula Evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
    f = "=IFERROR(INDEX(<addrMS>,MATCH(<d>,<addrE>,0),MATCH(<rw>,<addrA>,0)),0)"
    f = Replace(f, "<rw>", Cells(c.Row, 1).Address) ' col A
    f = Replace(f, "<addrMS>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$2:$S$" & lastRow)
    f = Replace(f, "<addrA>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$M$1:$S$1")
    f = Replace(f, "<d>", d.Address) ' 'header
    f = Replace(f, "<addrE>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow)
```